# sum duplicate subset rows condition on a column of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

We can sum over duplicate rows of a subset of columns:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"source": [1, 1, 3, 1, 1],
                   "target":[2, 2, 5, 3, 3],
                   "value": [0.5, 1.0, 1.51, 0.2, 0.5]})
print(df)
print(df.groupby(['source','target'], as_index=False)["value"].sum())
```

```sh
   source  target  value
0       1       2   0.50
1       1       2   1.00
2       3       5   1.51
3       1       3   0.20
4       1       3   0.50

   source  target  value
0       1       2   1.50
1       1       3   0.70
2       3       5   1.51
```

how to condition on duplicate rows, for example only duplicate rows with target 2

the output should be like this:

```sh
   source  target  value
0       1       2   1.50
2       3       5   1.51
3       1       3   0.20
4       1       3   0.50
```

Edit:
the other duplicate rows can be dropped (`df.drop_duplicates(subset=["source","target"])`) later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said the other duplicate rows can be dropped later, here is one approach that would first remove the duplicate rows where target is not `2` and then groups and aggregate the remaining rows

```
c = ['source', 'target']
df[~df.duplicated(c) | df['target'].eq(2)].groupby(c, as_index=False).sum()
```

---

```
   source  target  value
0       1       2   1.50
1       1       3   0.20
2       3       5   1.51
```

Comment: Not the OP's desired output tho.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a Boolean index to filter the DataFrame with the section to `groupby` and not to `groupby` then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the DataFrame pieces together like:

```
# Condition to filter DataFrame with (target == 2)
m = df['target'].eq(2)
new_df = pd.concat([
    # DataFrame rows that meet condition `m`
    df[m].groupby(['source', 'target'], as_index=False)["value"].sum(),
    # DataFrame rows which do not (~) meet the condtion
    df[~m]
])
```

`new_df`:

```
   source  target  value
0       1       2   1.50
2       3       5   1.51
3       1       3   0.20
4       1       3   0.50
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try `groupby` and `duplicated` with `agg`, `sum` and `first`:

```
df.groupby((~(df.duplicated(['source', 'target'], keep=False) & df['target'].eq(2))).cumsum()).agg({'source': 'first', 'target': 'first', 'value': sum})
```

Or just assign the column names as list:

```
cols = ['source', 'target']
df.groupby((~(df.duplicated(cols, keep=False) & df['target'].eq(2))).cumsum()).agg({**dict.fromkeys(cols, 'first'), 'value': sum})
```

---

```
   source  target  value
0       1       2   1.50
1       3       5   1.51
2       1       3   0.20
3       1       3   0.50
```